# Editing Outlook email templates

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, windows-registry, templates

I have saved an Email as an Outlook template. So I have a file called `DemoTemplate.oft` now. The template is fine, I can double click it and send an email. So far, so good. I now need to edit the email template.

For all other MS Office template files, the default action is "New", which creates a new file from the template and in the context menu I find "Open", which opens the template directly, so it will be manipulated. Here's that on a German system:

[image: Word example]

For Outlook, however, the default action is "Open", and unlike Word or Excel, hitting the save button will not update the template. Instead it saves an email in the draft folder.I thought that the two functions just might have been swapped mistakenly, so I tried "New" as well - with the same effect.

[image: Outlook example]

I have then looked up the Registry in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` and followed from `.oft` to `Outlook.File.oft.15`. This shows me that the two commands are indeed the same. Both commands are set to

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE" /t "%1"
```

What do I need to change in order to make Outlook treat templates like Word and Excel do?

I know I can open the email template and then choose "Save as ...", change the file type, select the folder, enter the name etc. But I'd like it a bit simpler.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, I'm afraid that it is by design that we could only modify the Outlook template via "Save as ..." and we could not make Outlook treat templates like Word and Excel do.